# Raspbian autostarting a PyQT5 UI that has Serial communication

Tags: raspbian

I'd designed a python software that required to start right after boot into system.
I'd use `sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to add in `@python3 /home/pi/X/exe.py`

Before I'd include serial communication into the apps, everything works fine.

But after I'd add in serial, the autostart had failed.

So, how to autostart on boot a PyQt5 based serial comn.-able apps in Raspbian Jessie?

Comment: Do the user that run the PyQt5 program have rights to use the serial port?

Comment: Erm, I believe I have. @MatsK does you mean I have to setup rights for the co-responding serial port before making it autostart?

Answer (score 0):

I'd decided to reflash the image and my problem is solved.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.